# setInterval(); not working. I am trying to get my countdown to go down but it gets stuck and I can't seem to find whats wrong with it

Tags: javascript

```
(HTML)
 <div class="countdownholder">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="contentHeader">
                <h3>Days until my 22nd birthday</h3>

            </div>

            <div class="countdownHolder">
                <div class="time1" id="timeDay"><p></p></div>
                <div class="time1" id="timeHours"></div>
                <div class="time1" id="timeMinutes"></div>
                <div class="time1" id="timeSeconds"></div>
            </div>
            


        </div>

    </div>
    
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

```
(javascript)
var birthdayDate = new Date('Jan 04, 2024 00:01:00');
var currentTime = new Date();
var timeLeft = birthdayDate - currentTime; (for current day)
var suspectedDays = document.getElementById("timeDay");
var suspectedHours = document.getElementById("timeHours"); 
var suspectedMins = document.getElementById("timeMinutes");
var suspectedSecs = document.getElementById("timeSeconds");



function getTime(){

    //making the computer do math to get current time//
  var d = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var h = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var m = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var s = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    suspectedDays.innerHTML = d;
    suspectedHours.innerHTML = h;
    suspectedMins.innerHTML = m;
    suspectedSecs.innerHTML = s;

}




setTimeout(getTime, 1000); //<-- Does not work 

getTime(birthdayDate, currentTime(current time), timeLeft);
```

I was recommended to use the interval command but it does not go to plan and the countdown freezes. I looked at other examples but thus end up on the same problem as before.  my freidd even looked at this and was stumped.

Comment: i think he may be stumped because either that code is incomplete or you've mutilated it.  GetTime doesn't take parameters but in that call at the bottom you are passing three parameters to it.  These won't be used.  A setTimeout will only one once so that's absolutely not going to work.  You need an interval set to, say, one second (although that's really ludicrous) so you can update.  I suggest you post your actual complete code, not this mutilated version of it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put `currentTime` in the function `getTime()` so that `getTime` methods can calculate remain time whenever called.

```
function getTime(){
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var timeLeft = birthdayDate - currentTime;

  var d = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var h = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var m = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var s = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    suspectedDays.innerHTML = d;
    suspectedHours.innerHTML = h;
    suspectedMins.innerHTML = m;
    suspectedSecs.innerHTML = s;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving `var currentTime` and `var timeLeft` into the function `getTime` so they actually get re-evaluated each time the `getTime` function runs. As written it seems like this will write the same time to the elements every time the function runs.